# YouTube updates not showing up

Tags: updates, youtube

I have the YouTube app built into my device but the problem is when I open the YouTube app, there's always a reminder to get that latest version of it. When I click that reminder, it directs me to Google Play, and there is no update button there. It isn't showing on the My Apps list too. How do I update the YouTube app now?

Comment: Try clearing cache of Play Store and Youtube. You could also clear data to be sure, but you might have to log in again in that case

Comment: you may also try going into Settings app and choose YouTube app. And try to "Uninstall updates" option. Note that, doing this will REMOVE your Offline videos from YouTube app which you may have downloaded earlier.